# SQL Server 2012: Select Top n based on multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Pretty new to SQL here - help would be much appreciated. I have a table with `Region`, `Month`, `Member ID`, and `Sales` (with multiple transactions per member).  I just want to extract the top 2 members, based on sum of sales, per region, per month....so essentially:

```
Region   Month     MemberID   Sales
-----------------------------------------
  1      1/1/2013     A       $200 
  2      2/1/2013     B       $300 
  1      1/1/2013     A       $100 
  1      1/1/2013     B        $50 
  2      1/1/2013     D       $500 
  2      2/1/2013     C       $200
```

Becomes:

```
Region  Month   Member ID   Sales
-----------------------------------------
1   1/1/2013    A    $300 
1   1/1/2013    B    $50 
2   1/1/2013    D    $500 
2   1/1/2013    B    $200
```

Ultimately, there will be 10 regions, and I'd like to take the top 5 sales by member for each region, each month.

Comment: `I just want to extract the top 2 members` what do you want to happen if there's a tie for second place? Should three row be returned or is there some sort of tie breaker? If there's no tie breaker are you ok the tie being broken arbitrarily?

Comment: Your sample isn't particularly helpful as it's just removing the entries for February.  Do you want the top 2 members by sales per region, per month, or do you want the top 5 sales by member per region per month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `row_number()`:

```
select region, month, MemberId, sales
from (select region, month, MemberId, sum(sales) as sales
             row_number() over (partition by region, month order by sum(sales) desc) as seqnum
      from table t
      group by region, month, MemberId
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Gordon.  One issue I'm seeing is that I'd like to have the just the top 5 spending members...what I have now has a yields a RowNumber of '1' to every line:


; with T1 as

(
select
 LOCATION,
 REGION,
 [YR_MO SERVICE],
 MEMBER_NBR,
 sum(cast(paid as money)) as Paid
from
 [Main Table]
where
 LOCATION = '12'
group by
 location,
 region,
 [YR_MO SERVICE],
 MEMBER_NBR
),

T2 as
(
select *,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Location, region, [yr_mo service], member_nbr ORDER BY Paid Desc) as RN
 FROM
  T1
)

select *
from
 T2
where
 RN <= 5

Comment: You have too many columns in your `partition by`.  I note my answer doesn't have `MemberId` in the `partition by`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are worried about ties (any you probably are as @Conrad Frix pointed out) you may prefer RANK() to ROW_NUMBER().

I'll borrow sample data, use CTEs for clarity, apply my preferred formatting, and provide a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8a7dd/1).

```
CREATE TABLE MemberSales (
  Region INT
 ,SalesMonth DATETIME
 ,MemberID CHAR(1)
 ,Sales FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO MemberSales VALUES (1, '1/1/2013', 'A', 200);
INSERT INTO MemberSales VALUES (2, '2/1/2013', 'B', 300);
INSERT INTO MemberSales VALUES (1, '1/1/2013', 'A', 100);
INSERT INTO MemberSales VALUES (1, '1/1/2013', 'C', 300);
INSERT INTO MemberSales VALUES (1, '1/1/2013', 'D', 100);
INSERT INTO MemberSales VALUES (1, '1/1/2013', 'B', 50);
INSERT INTO MemberSales VALUES (2, '1/1/2013', 'D', 500);
INSERT INTO MemberSales VALUES (2, '2/1/2013', 'C', 200);

;WITH SalesTotalByMember AS (
  SELECT Region
        ,SalesMonth
        ,MemberID
        ,SUM(Sales) AS Sales
    FROM MemberSales
   GROUP BY Region
           ,SalesMonth
           ,MemberID
), Ranked AS (
  SELECT Region
        ,SalesMonth
        ,MemberID
        ,Sales
        ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Region, SalesMonth ORDER BY SALES DESC) rnk
    FROM SalesTotalByMember
) 
SELECT *
  FROM Ranked
 WHERE rnk <= 2
 ORDER BY region
         ,SalesMonth
         ,rnk
```

Comment: This is an awesome answer. I'm sort of stunned that this question doesn't have more views nor more votes.

Answer (score 0):

I see it's easier to use ***TOP*** statement

```
create table Table1
(
    Region int,
    Month datetime,
    [Member ID] char(1),
    Sales float
);

insert into Table1 values (1, '1/1/2013', 'A', 200);
insert into Table1 values (2, '2/1/2013', 'B', 300);
insert into Table1 values (1, '1/1/2013', 'A', 100);
insert into Table1 values (1, '1/1/2013', 'B', 50);
insert into Table1 values (2, '1/1/2013', 'D', 500);
insert into Table1 values (2, '2/1/2013', 'C', 200);

select Top 5 Region, Month, [Member ID], sum(Sales) As [Total Sales] 
  from table1
group by Region, Month, [Member ID]
order by Region, Month, [Member ID], sum(Sales) desc
```

Results are:

```
    REGION  MONTH              MEMBER ID    TOTAL SALES
       1    January, 01 2013    A   300
       1    January, 01 2013    B   50
       2    January, 01 2013    D   500
       2    February, 01 2013   B   300
       2    February, 01 2013   C   200
```

Comment: From OP: "Ultimately, there will be 10 Regions, and I'd like to take the top 5 sales by member for each region, each month."  This query does not achieve what the OP is after.

Comment: This will only return 5 records, period.  Not 5 per region.