# How to limit result for each item in IN list

Tags: sql-server

Found similar questions, but none is clear enough to solve my problem.
I need to find the top 3 for each of the groups.
This query works, but only for one. I need it to work for a 'IN (...)' list.

```
SELECT top 3 a.make, a.model, a.colour, b.price, c.dealerCode FROM Dealers c
INNER JOIN Cars a on a.make=c.make
INNER JOIN Prices b on a.make=b.make
WHERE c.dealerName='A' and a.make='VW' and b.price_range='X1'
```

Ideally I want my arguments in an IN list like, and the top 3 from each of them:

```
WHERE c.dealerName IN ('A', 'B', 'C') and a.make IN ('VW','FIAT','Volvo') and b.price_range ='X1'
```

Although this would work with IN, it would only give me the top 3 of the entire list, while I need the top 3 of each dealer/make combination.
(slightly simplified example)

(for the moment I need just the top 3 of each, in whatever order they come)
I suspect I need to use GROUP BY, but can't get that it to work.
Thanks

Comment: Where do the values for `('A', 'B', 'C')` etc. come from ?

Comment: `IN` works. The query you posted will work and produce rows that have any combination of those values. What's your question? What did you expect and what did you get? What does `best 3 deals` mean?

Comment: I just kept the arguments simple. instead of 'A' it would be a dealerName, in my database table. For whoever downgraded this question, I've been trying to get this working for several hours now, looking at answers and various websites referred to through stackoverflow on similar questions

Comment: A `top` without `order by` makes little sense. I think you want to use a ranking function like `DENSE_RANK()`

Comment: I disagree, a top without a order-by makes perfectly sense if you just want 3 examples rather than a thousand, as I would get in my case. Also, an order-by is not part of the problem. But feel free to add if you know the answer to my question. (my database is not really into cars, that's just to make it understandable)

Comment: Yes, IN works, I just get over a thousand entries per combination found. That's not what I need.

Comment: @user3211098, I said it makes little sense, not no sense (bearing in mind I have no idea what you are doing). For sure, there are cases where you don't care. As for a solution, as I said you should look into ranking functions. There are a great many examples available already.

Comment: Ranking will help you solve the problem. There are some examples [here](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-rank-function/), search for `price_rank <= 3`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server 2012: Select Top n based on multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770604/sql-server-2012-select-top-n-based-on-multiple-criteria)

Comment: I don't see how ranking functions can solve it.Ordering, ranking is not the problem. the problem is that I get far too many answers for each combination. I just want a few results . E.g. in the above example, say dealer 'A' has 500 VWs on sale in my price-class, I just want to see 3 of them. Don't care which 3, but not 500. But I also want to see 3 of his Volvos. etc etc. At the moment I'm doing a one by one SQL for this (it's a business problem) and that works, but a trickier one is where I need the list off ALL makes on sale ( just 3 of each, but I don't know the makes on beforehand)

Comment: So for each dealer/make combination you distribute a number (you rank them) and select only the ones lower or equal to 3. something like `DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY c.dealername, a.make ORDER BY c.dealername, a.make) AS DR` (in a subquery), and select `WHERE DR <= 3`.

Comment: I tried that, using the website mentioned and the code theer , adjusted for my needs with the JOINs, and got something working, but I get everything. All have a rank of 1, and there is no limit of 3, so on a simple 2 argument IN I get almost 3000 records

Comment: @user3211098 could you edit your attempt into your question?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're looking for something like this.  In a common table expression (CTE), a row_number sequence is assigned to unique combinations `PARTITION BY` of `c.dealerName, a.make, b.price_range` and the ordering is not specified, i.e. `ORDER BY` is (select null).  To remove duplicates only 1 row is selected per (dealerName, make, price_range) triplet.  Using the de-duplicated result of the first CTE, another row number is assigned to unique combinations of dealerName and make.  Then the 'top 3' are chosen for each group (dealerName, Make) by limiting the 'dm_rn' row number value in the outer query to <=3.

```
with 
rn_cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by c.dealerName, a.make, b.price_range 
                                 order by (select null)) rn
    from Dealers c
         join Cars a on a.make=c.make
         join Prices b on a.make=b.make
    where c.dealerName IN ('A', 'B', 'C') 
          and a.make IN ('VW','FIAT','Volvo') 
          and b.price_range ='X1'),
dm_cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by dealerName, make
                                 order by (select null)) dm_rn
    from rn_cte
    where rn=1)
select make, model, colour, price, dealerCode
from dm_cte 
where dm_rn<=3
order by dealerName, make, price_range;
```

Comment: That's absolutely brilliant, yes it does the trick precisely. It took me a while to understand what it is doing , and I had to adapt to the actual table names.

Comment: Additionally, it is very fast! quicker then my single use SQL above

Comment: Glad it helped!  Unlike most questions this one I could actually recognize the make names and the objects all made sense.  I know what a car dealer is lol.  Cheers!